# define a constant in verilog (for synthesis)

Tags: verilog

I'm writing some Verilog code for synthesis.
My block has a reg type A, that has to have always the same value. 
In order not to have syntax errors, I wrote the following:

```
module dig_block ( OUT, OUTN, in , OUTlevelL, mode_1, mode_0 , rst);
    output [11:0] OUT, OUTN;
    input [11:0] in, OUTlevelL;
    input  mode_1, mode_0, rst;  
    reg [11:0] OUT, OUTN;

    reg [11:0] A;   
    integer B; 


    always @(ck or rst) 
    if(~rst)
        begin
            A =512;   
            B =in[10:0];

            case  ({mode_1, mode_0})  
            2'b00:  begin     
                    OUT=A-B;   
                    OUTN=~OUT;
                end

            default:   begin  
                OUT=OUTlevelL;
                OUTN=~OUT;
                end
            endcase
        end
    else
        begin  
            A =512;
            B =0;     
            OUT =0;
            OUTN=1;
        end 
endmodule
```

Is it possible to define A before "always"? I don't know what is the common practice for quantities that has to be fixed and are not inputs, nor outputs. I don't want unnecessary ports placed during synthesis.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `ck` is not declared and the way you wrote your always block, your code will be treated as pure combinational logic with no flops.

Comment: Pretty sure `always @(ck or rst)` should be `always @(posedge ck or posedge rst)`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm avoiding posedge, because I need both edges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define it as Local parameter. This will confine its scope inside this module only.

```
module dig_block ( OUT, OUTN, in , OUTlevelL, mode_1, mode_0 , rst);
        output [11:0] OUT, OUTN;
        input [11:0] in, OUTlevelL;
        input  mode_1, mode_0, rst;  
        reg [11:0] OUT, OUTN;

        localparam [11:0] A=512;
```

Comment: Thank you! But how will the localparam be synthesized? My goal is to have a register with fixed (not programmable) inputs

Comment: Localparam will come a hardcoded value. Something which can't be changed and values drived as combination of 0 and 1 using Ground and Voltage.
You don't need a register for fixed values.